# make searchBar and searchDisplayController look like normal input field

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've got a search bar within a UITableView, but when I click the search bar, the UITableView takes up the entire space of the ViewController while it should always perform as a subview and stay in the width it was given. Secondly, I want to get the search bar to look like a normal input field as on paper: just a straight line underneath instead of borders all around.

It'd be great if somehow could answer both of the questions asked here.

I've included a visual for reference, the first is the view before, the other one when the UISearchBar is active.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ASwT.png)

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JokW8.png)

[image]

**Update**

I've figured out how to stop the UITableView from going fullscreen, by replacing the `UISearchDisplayController` for a `UISearchBar`. However, now my search functionality does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: in order to prevent the TableView from going fullscreen, I changed `UISearchDisplayController` for a `UISearchBar` and changed the delegate methods of search into: `-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`